# Spring boot - what can application.properties store

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating a application which will use javax.mail to get mail from gmail and then using spring boot to make attachments from the received email available.

I see spring boot application.properties can store various key/value pairs listed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties) - but can it be used to store other key/value pairs?

Specifically I am thinking of the gmail username and password for javax.mail.

Comment: techically gmail username and password are just strings, and can. but from security perspecitve, configure it in environment variables(or elsewhere, depends how you deploy) is safer.

Comment: yea, it safer to save in environment variable or retrieve from SSM or vault

Answer (score 3):

You can store any custom key/value pair in `application.properties`. This:

```
your.custom.key=your.value
```

is totally valid. Then you get the value as any other property:

```
@Value("${your.custom.key}")
private String value;
```