# Add custom variables in application.properties of Spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, authentication, application.properties

I am using `Unirest.get("http://localhost").basicAuth("user", "password1!").asString();`
in the spring-boot application.
Every time I am calling this I have to hardcode the username and password.
How can I put username and password in application.properties once and for all? I don't want to use any class or static variables.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: You can store anything in application properties and then retrieve it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434581/spring-boot-what-can-application-properties-store/71435400#71435400) should help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use @Value annotation. For example:

application.properties file look like this:

```
user.name=test
user.password=test
```

Your code looks like:

```
public class YourService {
    @Value("${user.name}")
    private String userName;
    @Value("${user.password}")
    private String password;
}
```

If your variable give you Null value. It means you are trying to access variable before injecting value. So try this code:

```
@Service
public class YourClass {
    private static final Logger LOG = 
    LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class.getSimpleName());

    @Value("${user.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${user.password}")
    private String password;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        
        LOG.info("username=" + username);
        LOG.info("username=" + password);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've used it, but its populating the variable as null.

Comment: @ManushreeVishwakarma Can I see your class? because Value annotation will work with Component level annotations (Service, Component etc...)

Comment: the class is annotated with Service

Comment: @ManushreeVishwakarma can you give us whole code of your service class. Because I am guess, you are trying to access your variable before initialize it.